# IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection when running oracle DB as docker container

Tags: java, oracle, docker

Based on:

https://github.com/fuzziebrain/docker-oracle-xe

I am running an oracle express db as a docker container. From my host OS (ubuntu 19.04) I can successfully connect to the db using:

```
$ sqlplus sampleschema/12345@localhost:32118/XE
Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL>
```

Now I would like to start up another docker container and run a small java application that connects to the oracle db. The java application I am running is a slightly modified version of `JDBCExample`:

https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/connect-to-oracle-db-via-jdbc-driver-java/

```
package samples;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JDBCExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String jdbcUrl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:32118/xe";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            jdbcUrl=args[0];
            System.out.println ("JDBC URL is: " + jdbcUrl);
        }

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                jdbcUrl, "sampleschema", "12345")) {
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

In the `run.sh` script of the container image (being called in the `ENTRYPOINT` in the dockerfile) for this application I have

```
JDBC_URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//172.18.0.2:32118/xe"
java -cp "/opt/sample:/opt/sample/ojdbc8.jar:/opt/sample/sample-app-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" samples.JDBCExample $JDBC_URL
```

where I got `172.18.0.2` by running `ifconfig` in the oracle container. But I get this error:

```
SQL State: 08006
IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

And I have verified that the jars listed above are in the expected location in the sample application container.

Some docker details. I start the oracle container with:

```
  docker run \
  -p 32118:1521 \
  -p 35518:5500 \
  --name=oracle-xe \
  --network=sample-network \
  oracle-xe:18c
```

and the sample application container with:

```
  docker run --network=sample-network -it --name debug-app-container debug-app-image
```

so they are running on the same network.

Why does the connection fail to the oracle DB when its executed inside the sample java application container?

Also if I run the `samples.JDBCExample` class on my host with `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:32118/xe` using the exact same sample application jar and ojdc8.jar file it works fine (printing `Connected to the database!` as expected).

Comment: use `oracle-xe` instead of `localhost` in your jdbc connection string

Comment: @michalk is right since you use the same network, you can use the container name `oracle-xe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You connect both of your containers to the same network so your containers will be able to communicate over this network and continer names will be DNS names resolved to their IP.

So your connection string should look like :

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-xe:1521/xe
```

and `oracle-xe` will be resolved to database container IP over this common network. And also remember about the port. I assume your DB will be exposed at `1521` port at the DB container.